# Want to Export obj without applying modifier 3.1

Tags: modifiers, export

my workflow involved taking low poly models then applying a few modifiers to get the looks I like, then exporting both low-poly and higher poly but now there is no button for export without modifiers(it use to be there 3.0)

Comment: 3.1 removed that option

Comment: Yes, my bad. It was written in the tiltle.

Comment: I just downloaded 3.1. It seems to be missing indeed while FBX and a few other formats still have the options. The only thing that comes into my mind is to have a duplicate of the object without the modifier and export the two separately.

Comment: Hello and welcome, try to report that as a bug under Help (inside Blender) > Report Bug